# Swift GEOJson Codable object

Tags: swift, geojson

I am trying to access coordinates within a GEOJson I receive. I created `Codable Structs`.

My `GEOJson` `codable` `Geometry` struct is like this:

```
struct ServiceArea : Codable {

    let area : [Area]?
    let vehicleType : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case area = "area"
        case vehicleType = "vehicle_type"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        area = try values.decodeIfPresent([Area].self, forKey: .area)
        vehicleType = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .vehicleType)
    }
}

struct Area : Codable {

    let geometry : Geometry?
    let properties : Property?
    let type : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case geometry
        case properties
        case type = "type"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        geometry = try Geometry(from: decoder)
        properties = try Property(from: decoder)
        type = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
    }
}
    struct Geometry : Codable {
        let coordinates : [[[Float]]]?
        let type : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coordinates = "coordinates"
        case type = "type"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        coordinates = try values.decodeIfPresent([[[Float]]].self, forKey: .coordinates)
        type = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
    }
}
```

But when I try to access .coordinates, it is always nil.

Comment: Are you sure coordinates is a 3 dimensional array? Wouldn’t a 2 dimensional make more sense, [[Float]]?

Comment: Make the properties non-optional, comment-out the `init` method and `catch` the error. That's a good example why declaring everything carelessly as optional is not a good practice. Nothing happens and you have no clue why.